# Asp.net core API authentication with Azure Bearer token

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, bearer-token, azure-authentication

I have now spent weeks on this, including reading everything I can possibly find on the subject, so please don't shoot me down saying I should do my research or to post what I've already written - I have really, really done my research but cannot find the answer that works for my brain and what I have written all works, it's the concept I'm struggling with.

What I'm struggling with is the concept of how I secure an asp.net Core API endpoint using a Beaer token obtained from Azure (via Teams Toolkit) when the two systems are separate and potentially don't know about each other's installations or shared keys used to create the bearer token.

This is the scenario:

There is a Teams "Tab App" which customers will install on their local instances of M365.  This Teams Tab app will acquire the token from Azure.  From this token we would like to get their email address and name but we have to first validate that token has not been altered in transit (we can get the token from Teams, no problem - good so far).

What we would then like to do is pass that token in the authorization header when the call is made to the API.  The API knows nothing about the Teams Tab app install as it was done on a customer's M365 tenancy, and their install of the Tab App knows nothing about the API apart from the URL to call and the requirement to pass the bearer token.

Unless I have misunderstood (which hopefully I have), everything I have read on this seems to require a shared secret shared between the "client" and is required at API instantiation within the program.cs class -- this won't be possible as multiple customers will be calling the API from lots of Teams Tab App installs (all separate organisations), and in any case, it's Azure providing the token not us creating it.

This seems to rule-out the "built in" authentication model we can add to the pipeline in program.cs.  Therefore, are we only left with the option to manually validate each request containing the bearer token coming into the API as (I believe) we know the public key used to sign the token in the first place because Microsoft obv publish this address for common use?

Hopefully that makes sense to someone out there and will kick my arse for getting it all wrong, and help guide me into the light - help me Obi-Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope!

Comment: Can these links help you: [Get bearer token from Azure for protected .net core 6 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/968397/get-bearer-token-from-azure-for-protected-net-core.html), [How to secure a Web API built with ASP.NET Core using the Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/how-to-secure-a-web-api-built-with-aspnet-core-using-the-azure-ad-b2c/)?

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately not, I've read both of those already and there appears still to be the issue of having to know information that we can't possibly know.  They are great if you are consuming your own API from your own client apps, but when you have customers installing client apps in their own environments it no longer helps.